# How do I protect an Angular 2 SPA from XSS attacks?

Tags: javascript, java, rest, angular, spring-security

I need to secure my SPA from XSS.
I use Angular 2 for the client side and REST services in JAVA on the server.

I know that Angular treats all inputs in the template as unsecure and sanitize and escapes html tags, etc.
there is also the protection built in the browsers using the X-XSS header.

Do I need to do some protection on the server side? handle the data sent from/to the client?

if so is there a java library that wraps all the requests and secure them from XSS?

one of the requests is to save a password and I want to allow special characters, how do I not change the password`s characters and still being secure?

Thanks!

Comment: U can't do any impressive protection server side Just some simple injection protections to ur server XSS does all stuffs client side

Answer (score 0):

Never trust the client! For your Java Backend you can use for example the [AntiSamy](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_AntiSamy_Project) Project from the OWASP.  It helps you that clients don't supply malicious cargo code via HTML/CSS that get persisted on the server.

Comment: AntiSamy is only an API, right? I still need to handle each of the inputs and decide whether to accept it or filter it out. Or did I miss anything?